# Create new custom schemas with nested structure in CDP

Tags: cdp

Can anyone confirm around the feasibility to create new schema's or extend/modify existing schemas such as Guest, Order etc. within Sitecore CDP interface.

Is there is a way for developers to create New Schemas with nested JSON structure similar to that of Order, Session, Guest, Product etc. within Sitecore CDP/Boxever. As per documentation the only way to include and associate additional information with Guest profile is in the form of attributes - Key/Value pair supported through Data Extensions. We have a use case, where we want to add some customer Loyalty and service request related data which may have a nested structure based on brands and region.

Can someone please guide through a way where we can create new schema or extend existing Guest schema to allow nested pair of objects.
Note - I have access to the Boxever Sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** As you noticed, *Guest extentions* support only primitive values.

I found only one workaround how to bypass JSON objects to *Guest extention*: **stringify an object** *(by using JSON.stringify(data))*:
[image]

[image]

And it can be parsed when you need to access to object values:

```
(function () {

for (var i = 0; i < guest.dataExtensions.length; i++) {
 if (guest.dataExtensions[i].name === 'Ext' && guest.dataExtensions[i].key === 'custom') {
      var ext = guest.dataExtensions[i].values;
      
      var test = JSON.parse(ext.test);
      print(test[0].a);
      print(test[0].b);
      
      return test;
    }
}

 })();
```

[image]

I agree that this way is not very convenient, but I did not find an alternative.

**P.S.** You can pass any types of data strusture in Events *(if you find a solution for your case how to do it at the event level)*:

```
    const boxeverEvent = { 
      browser_id: Boxever.getID(), 
      channel: 'WEB', 
      type: 'YOUR_EVENT_NAME', 
      language: 'EN', 
      pos: window.location.host, 
      currency: currency || 'EUR', 
      page: '/', 
      ext: YOUR_JSON_OBJECT, 
    };
```

[image]

**2.** Second way is to do request to your service to get this informations *(as alternative to storage in CDP)*. You can see example in my blog: https://www.brimit.com/blog/cdp-4-how-to-use-ai-connections.

*If this option is better for your case, let me know, I`ll extend my answer with example.*

Comment: Thanks for putting up such a detailed response.  I believe this is the only way of being able to store nested/complex schema using Data extensions , until Sitecore extends CDP to provide a dedicated interface to define schemas, datasets for profile and events etc.